# Issues manually downloading the newest stable version of the ngx_pagespeed module

Tags: bash, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to download the ngx_pagespeed module so I can compile Nginx from source with it.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

I am using the instructions from https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

So I need to install the Ubuntu dependencies first, no trickiness there.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev unzip uuid-dev
```

After installing dependencies, you move on to the "Build Instructions" section. This is where I am completely thrown off. Here is the code I cannot decipher.

```
NPS_VERSION=1.12.34.2-stable
cd
wget 
https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/archive/v${NPS_VERSION}.zip
unzip v${NPS_VERSION}.zip
cd ngx_pagespeed-${NPS_VERSION}/
NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER=${NPS_VERSION/beta/}
NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER=${NPS_VERSION/stable/}
psol_url=https://dl.google.com/dl/page-speed/psol/${NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER}.tar.gz
[ -e scripts/format_binary_url.sh ] && psol_url=$(scripts/format_binary_url.sh PSOL_BINARY_URL)
wget ${psol_url}
tar -xzvf $(basename ${psol_url})  # extracts to psol/
```

First question- these two lines seem at odds to me.

```
NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER=${NPS_VERSION/beta/}
NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER=${NPS_VERSION/stable/}
```

I'm no bash expert, but wouldn't the second line negate the first? Why would they include both of these lines, particularly when the first line specifies that "NPS_VERSION=1.12.34.2-stable"?

Second question, if I stop running lines at "NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER=${NPS_VERSION/beta/}" and then run

```
echo "$NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER"
```

it returns "1.12.34.2-stable"

OK, weird. It seems to just be echoing the variable "NPS_VERSION", completely disregarding the partial string "/beta/" that is appended to "NPS_VERSION" in the variable "NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER".

So I set "NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER=${NPS_VERSION/stable/}"

Echo the variable again, but this time it returns "1.12.34.2-". Seriously, what is going on here?

Edit: I'm starting to think that something is seriously wrong with the documentation. I thought it was just me, but the fact that the variable "NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER" is returning such odd results leads me to believe that something else is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm no bash expert, but wouldn't the second line negate the first?

Yes, first line will be redundant.

> Echo the variable again, but this time it returns "1.12.34.2-".
>   Seriously, what is going on here?

This is bash substutution. Construction `${VAR/substring/to replace}` just replaces `substring` to `to replace` in `$VAR`. So, you just stripped "stable" string, this behavior is correct.

> I'm starting to think that something is seriously wrong with the
>   documentation. I thought it was just me, but the fact that the
>   variable "NPS_RELEASE_NUMBER" is returning such odd results leads me
>   to believe that something else is going on here.

Looks like this script is over-engineered.  Ignore it. Just download/unpack sources of nginx and your modules and then, in directory of nginx do:

```
./configure --add-module=/some/path/to/ngx_pagespeed-${NPS_VERSION}  (any extra flags of nginx here)
make
sudo make install
```

That all. Please note, what last command will install new nginx in your system and this installation done without package manager. If you **really** want it, remove any versions of nginx what been installed before.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain what was going on. I feel kind of silly now for not seeing that they were using string substitution to strip "stable" or "beta" off the end of the variable.